# SQL Performance Issues with Linked Servers with Owner Versus Reader Accounts

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have a query that runs perfectly when using a linked server with Reader rights. It returns in 1 second. Then, if I switch the linked server to have Owner rights, it will run/hang until I cancel the query.

To recap, exact same query and both linked servers are identical. The only difference is in one query the linked server only has Read rights and the other query the linked server only has Owner rights.

I would think that using the linked server with Owner rights would open up statistics/indexes and would be quicker but this is definitely not the case in this situation. I have viewed the SQL execution plans for both queries and both are very different. Can anyone explain why this is happening and explain why security rights are affecting the execution plans so drastically?

READER EXAMPLE

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    BOLINE.BO_ID, 2 AS SORTORDER 
FROM 
    REQ
JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM cp_BO_LN_READER 
     WHERE RQ_ID > '') BOLINE ON CAST(REQ.REQ_ID AS VARCHAR) = BOLINE.RQ_ID 

UNION 

SELECT 
    'ALL', 1 AS SORTORDER 
ORDER BY
    SORTORDER, BO_ID
```

OWNER EXAMPLE

Same as Reader example except switch cp_BO_LN_READER with CP_BO_LN_OWNER. These are synonyms that point to identical linked servers.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.